# Get Bootstrap 4 Vertical pills :after to line up with pills

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

So I have some vertical pills which have an :after class to create a triangle at the end of the pill as so :

```
.nav-link.active :after {
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 21px 0 21px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #bbcfd8;
}
```

The problem I have come across is that the triangle will not align with the pills themselves. I have created a codepen with the example I am using :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBjOKR

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `top:0` in this style and position: relative; on nav-link

```
.nav-link.active :after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -20px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 21px 0 21px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #bbcfd8;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link {
    position: relative;
}
```

See updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzNRM?editors=0110)

Comment: I knew it would be something as simple as this. Much Appreciated.